# In Win 8.1 & application(64-bit) , the convert System string to std wstring will be fail ? (C++)

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

In Win 8.1 && application(64-bit)

convert System string to std wstring  will be fail ?

what can i do ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this MSDN article? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1ae6tz5.aspx